# Custom View onMeasure vs onSizeChanged vs onLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-constraintlayout

I have implemented some custom views in Android and one of the most frequent problems I have is to adapt the layout to the screen, weather by matching the parent's content, `MATCH_PARENT`, or wrapping its own content, `WRAP_CONTENT`. The `ConstraintLayout`, for instance, does not support `WRAP_CONTENT`.

The trouble starts when I have to adapt the children size, which initially I was doing on `onLayout`. One use case of this is when I want to have children which width and height respect a certain aspect ratio; and the width grow as much as possible.

So, in my `onLayout`, if `changed` was `true` I had reset constraints reset. However, it was causing a loop, since it changes the layout again.

What would be the proper place to size the custom widget children?
`onSizeChanged` or `onMeasure`?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the constraintlayout does not support wrap_content". I use constraintlayouts that have their widths and heights set to wrap_content and it works correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not currently working with android anymore, it was so long ago, should I delete this question?